# How to update the value in sql server ?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Previously I have a default value of 2 for all records.

I need to change the 2 value to 3 for all records.
Please tell me how to update the new value in old records.

Comment: Really??? just see how many result you get if you type this question title on [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+to+update+the+value+in+sql+server+%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs&gfe_rd=cr&ei=27pXU7a1CKTR8geizYCoDA)

Comment: I can tell you what he has not tried: a book about SQL for beginners of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE <tableName> SET <field> = 3 WHERE <field> = 2
```